# Append <span> tag inside of <a> tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append span tag inside `.block-leftnav ul li .parent a`, so the  tag gets added only after the `.parent a` but what jquery does is, it adds the span tag after every a href tag on my page.

Below is the code I am using to acheive what I want:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.block-leftnav ul li .parent > a').append('<span class="glyphicon arrow"></span>');
});
```

It was a simple fix, I figured it out myself and also updated the above code. Just had to add the ">" before the "a" to target the anchor tags of that particular div.

Thanks Guys for your prompt response.

Comment: You don't have to use `jQuery.noConflict()` if you're only going to use `jQuery()` :) also, what's the HTML?

Comment: Are all of the `<a>` tags inside `.block-leftnav ul li .parent`? If so, you need to specify which `<a>` tag(s) that you want to add the `span`. You can use class or id of `<a>` for that purpose.

Comment: You only want to append it after one `a`?

Comment: @Muhammad create fiddle for the code

Comment: or wait -- You want to append it after any `a` with class `parent`?

Comment: I've updated the working code above. You guys can check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

one thing you can do it like this..

```
 $(function(){
              $("#my_id").append("<span>sdfsdfd</span>");
            })
```

give the id to your anchor tag

```
 <a id="my_id" href="sdsd.xyz">xyz</a>
```

This is the code which is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/bpf6t3Lw/1/

html

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').append("<span>Appended item</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.block-leftnav ul li .parent a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon arrow"></span>');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change any behavior.

Comment: It adds a span tag inside the a tag!

Comment: So would the code the user posted. :) There's another problem that this answer doesn't address -- we need the user to clarify the specific problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to append an arrow character inside any `a` element that has the class `parent`.

To do so, your selector needs to be `a.parent`, not `.parent a`. The former will search for `a` elements with the class `parent` while the latter will search for any `a` element inside an element with the class `parent`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.block-leftnav ul li a.parent')
        .append('<span class="glyphicon arrow"></span>');
});
```

If you want to find the `a` element inside a `li` that has class `parent`, use the same concept, but apply it to the `li`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.block-leftnav ul li.parent a')
        .append('<span class="glyphicon arrow"></span>');
});
```